# Installing Xamarin Mono for Android

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to install Xamarin Mono for Android but I am having a hard time. I installed the Java SDK and the Android SDK. Now when I run the Xamarin installer it says that it can not find the Android SDK then it goes on to download the SDK. After it gets to 100% it goes back to 0% and downloads again it keeps doing this over and over and never gets past this stage. Is there a way I can make it skip this step or a way to tell it that Android SDK is installed?

Comment: You can find installation logs in c:\users\<yourlogin>\appdata\local\xamarin\monoforandroid - see what's the actuall error, perhaps it's just a network issue.
As for skipping the step - Mono for Android needs specific packages in a specific location, but it will not do anything if you install Android SDK using the self-executable installer from Google. Our installer will then detect the Android SDK is present and will only configure the AVDs it needs.

Comment: Hi Grendel. Thank you for responding. What specific location does it need the packages to be. Could you please also clarify which packages they are. Is there also a manual method of doing these installs. I really need your help because I am dying to try out Mono.

Comment: By the way I am using Windows 7 and I can't seem to find the directory with the logs

Comment: The directory is hidden, use total commander or configure windows explorer to show hidden files and you'll see it.
I'm not sure why do you want to download the Android SDK yourself instead of letting the installer do the job? You will have to download all of the packages either way.
The MfA requirements are platform APIs 7, 8, 10, 12 and 14, system images for API 14
Regarding the location of Android SDK - if you use the sfx installer from Google, just let it do its job, our installer will detect that

Comment: Hi I use pay-per-usage internet so for me everytime the installer was trying to get the Android SDK I was getting charged. So what I did is I went into the folder c:\users\<yourlogin>\appdata\local\xamarin\monoforandroid\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\ and ran the SDK Manager there and installed all the required APIs, I then ran the Xamarin installer so it can configure the AVDs and finish the rest of the installs. This worked better for me.

Comment: So you did manually what the installer would do for you :) You downloaded the same amount of data, but if you're happy then I'm happy too :)

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.

1. Right click on the setup.exe file
2. Select 'Run as Administrator.

Comment: Thank you, so much. I was getting the 'Beta Expired' error message on windows 7 as the Mono for Android SDK I had was out of date, and the unified installer would always report that my Win7 setup was already installed. I also found this [link](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Problems-with-installing-monodroid-with-Android-SDK-td5661567.html) if the above doesn't work for others. All I was after was to get vs2010 to have the mono for android trial installed so I could try some sample apps in the emulator via visual studio 2010. thanks again, just adding search terms for google...